# Is there a way to access the complete list of headers from within .htacces?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, request-headers

I am able to access arbitrary *specific* headers from within .htaccess, e.g. the following snippet sets a server environment variable `INFO_COOKIE` directly fetched from the HTTP headers using mod_rewrite.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule .* - [E=INFO_COOKIE:%{HTTP:cookie}]
```

I tried if I could get the complete list of headers by

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule .* - [E=INFO_HEADERS:%{HTTP}]
```

however, I get an empty string.

Actually the HTTP headers are nothing more than plain text lines separated by line feeds from each other. The delimiter between headers and body is a blank line (double line feed). Technically it should be possible to get the raw headers section without any problems.

Is there any possibility to access the complete headers list / raw section from within the .htaccess file on an Apache server? Since I do have system root access to the server, the installation of any additional Apache modules would be a reasonable solution.

Comment: You can get it from PHP code

Comment: `apache_request_headers()` or the alias `getallheaders()`, I am aware of that. I consciously related the question not to PHP but Apache .htaccess. Thank you anyway.